# Why when animating an ImageView from left to right in two project , I receive different result?

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I inserted a video of two running project . My final goal is achieving result like first running project . I want the image enter from left to the screen and move to right and finally fill the screen and stop .
In the first sample project , By receive guides from friends on Stack Overflow , I finally achieved my desired result .
But when I copy the code to the second project ( my main project ) ,I received different result and the image stops in the center of screen .
why ?

I insert codes for first project

https://youtu.be/UlKiAb4H9Dg

Second project full layout is added in the end of code

```
imageView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            startImageAnimation();
        }
    });

private void startImageAnimation() {
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, 
"translationX", -(imageView.getWidth()), 0);
    animation.setDuration(3000);
    animation.start();
}

<ImageView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/grass"
android:id="@+id/image_anim"
/>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/awz" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_logo_up"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="شرکت توسعه نیشکر و صنایع جانبی"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text_logo_down"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="سامانه داده کاربر بیمه"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="156dp"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:src="@drawable/bahrevar" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_anim_grass"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/grass"

    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I used LinearLayout ion both of two project with match_parent for both height and width

Answer (score 0):

in the layout of the 2nd project, you have probably `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` instead of `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for the ImageView

Comment: in both project i used match_parent

Comment: show us the full layout, mainly of the second project

Comment: I updated the code with full layout of second project

Comment: I can suggest you to set a real value, for example android:layout_width="500dp", just to test if you have not a problem with the linearlayout. Also check in both project, orientation is the same

Comment: 500dp for LinearLayout or ImageView ?

Comment: 500dp for ImageView

Comment: i added , not receiving desired result

Comment: sure, but does the width is different. Put an higher value, like 1000dp. It seems the ImageView can't take the full witdth of its mother view. Also, check the drawable folder is the same (hdpi, xhdpi, or even nodpi). That can influence